# Plot Spectrogram of a wav audio file

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib

I want to plot Spectrogram of 30s of a audio file in wav. But I encountered error while doing so in python. How can I achieve my goal?

```
    import scipy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.io.wavfile
    sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read('595.wav')
    print (sample_rate, X.shape )
    plt.specgram(X, Fs=sample_rate, xextent=(0,30))
```

And error

```
    ValueError: only 1-dimensional arrays can be used
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is pretty clear: `ValueError: only 1-dimensional arrays can be used`.
In your case `X` is not 1-dimensional. You would find out by printing `X.shape`.

While I can't be certain without a complete example here, the best guess would be that you're having a stereo wav file, which has 2 channels. So you need to select if you want to plot the spectrogram for the left or the right channel. E.g. for the left channel:

```
plt.specgram(X[:,0], Fs=sample_rate, xextent=(0,30))
```